# Understanding an application of induction in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I understand what is done below, however I don't understand the induction used, especially not when applying $0\leq n$.

> If $s_n+1=f(s_n)$ with $|f′(x)|\leq 1/2$ prove that the sequence $s_n$ converges for $0\leq n$.
>
> **Proof:** For $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$ we may apply the Mean Value Theorem to find $c \in (x, y)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$\frac{|f(y) − f(x)|}{|y − x|}= |f(c)| \leq a<1.
> $$
>   Rearranging, we have $|f(x)−f(y)|\leq a|x−y|$ for all $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$. That is, $f$ is a "strict Banach contraction."
>
> For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $|s_n −s_{n+1}| = |f(s_{n−1})−f(s_n)|\leq a|s_{n−1} −s_n|$, according
>   to the hypothesis on $f$. Iterating this process and applying induction yields the
>   estimate
>   $|s_n − s_{n+1}|\leq a^n|s_0 − s_1|$.
>
> ....

Comment: Are you by any chance following [these solutions](https://math.berkeley.edu/~borisp/MA104/MA104solutions3.pdf)? (Also, you might consider "registering" an account by logging in with an OpenID provider. This will ensure that you retain some control over your posts; at the very least you will be able to edit your posts as long as you are logged in under the same account.)

Answer (score 0):

So, we form sequential, iterative steps as follows

$$\begin{align}
|s_{n+1}-s_n|&\le a |s_{n}-s_{n-1}|\\\\
&\le a\cdot \left(a\,\,|s_{n-1}-s_{n-2}|\right)\\\\
&= a^2|s_{n-1}-s_{n-2}| \\\\
&\le a^3|s_{n-2}-s_{n-3}| \\\\
&\le \cdots \\\\
&\le a^n |s_{n-(n-1)}-s_{n-(n)}|\\\\
&=a^n |s_{1}-s_{0}|
\end{align}$$

If $|a|<1$, then the sequence converges.  For the problem here, $|f'|\le 1/2<1$.

Comment: why do the  s_n's turn to s_1 and s_0?

Comment: $n-(n-1)=1$ and $n-n=0$.  So, after the $n$th iteration, we arrive at the last step.

Comment: also how do you do the inductive step? In other words how do I show  |s_n+2−s_n+1|≤a|s_n+1−s_n| ?